# How to kill jQuery before filling html returned from ajax call?

Tags: jquery, live

I'm using an ajax function that builds fill the `innerHTML` of a span and then build the jquery function. The first time I call the jquery function it works fine, yet if I called the ajax function again the jquery click function is being called twice, and if i call it once more the jquery get called 3 times and so on. This the jquery method I'm using:

```
$(".delete_mail").live('click', function() {
                                     $(this).delete_mail();
                                    });
```

I tried the `.die` before filling the `innerHTML` yet it did not help. I want to remove the jquery `live` method before filling the `innerHTML` so it wont be duplicated.

Please help.

Comment: Is what I'm having is cause of .live? Is there a way to have .live being called only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *.live()* function binds an handler to an event for all current and **future** matched elements.

So, in general, you should call *.live()* only once, otherwise it will keep adding new handlers.

Try moving your *.live()* call to the *onload* event and call it only once, the handler will automatically bind to the new elements added via the Ajax call.

Comment: I did $(document).ready(function() {
$(".delete_mail").live('click', function() {
                                     $(this).delete_mail();
                                    });
});